# Python: separate rows of arrays into columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, data-cleaning

I have a csv file that contains one column and many rows like this format,

```
[[118 4 3 -169.0 246]]
```

How can I separate each number in a column?

The final result should be a data frame like this,

```
 Id   number  userId  location  area 
 118   4       3      -169.0    246
```

Comment: so you don't really have a CSV file. You have a file where every row looks like `[[118 4 3 -169.0 246]]`?

Comment: @kwsp It is stored in a csv. Yes, every row looks like this.

Comment: I guess what kwsp meant was that if what you had was a CSV file, your rows should look like this: `118,4,3,-169.0,246`

Comment: @MikolajBuchwald Thanks. But no, one column and every rows are stored like this  [[118 4 3 -169.0 246]]

Comment: Ok, that clarifies things. I see that @kwsp already answered your question. Have a nice day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a string `[[118 4 3 -169.0 246]]`, you can parse it into a list of floats like this

```py
s = "[[118 4 3 -169.0 246]]"
assert s[1] == "["
assert s[-1] == "]"

s = s[2:-2]
nums = [float(v) for v in s.split(" ")]
print(nums)  # [118.0, 4.0, 3.0, -169.0, 246.0]
```

Then you can just parse every line of the file like this, create a list of list of numbers and create a DataFrame from there.